# npm package installation via Package vs Command Line

Tags: node.js, npm, package, installation

What is the difference between these two installation methods for some npm packages?

This excerpt is from the installation section for [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug):

**Package**

via npm:

```
$ npm install pug
```

---

**Command Line**

After installing the latest version of Node.js, install with:

```
$ npm install pug-cli -g
```

---

So these are my questions:

- What are the advantages of using either of these two methods?
- Why are these packages named differently (pug vs pug-cli)?  I've noticed that some npm packages are suffixed with "-cli", command line interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install pug`: This is basically used to install the node module pug within the dir you run this command from. Once installed it lets you use pug with the project.

`npm install pug-cli -g`: This is installing the pug's command line interface. The -g flag installs it globally which means, you could basically initiate pug-cli from anywhere.

Now, the CLI's in general provides a lot of methods on top of the underlying modules. These methods are not something you would need in your code, but more as convenience methods, like say starting a server, or for the case of pug, the CLI provides a methods to render all the templates in a particular directory. 
As the part of your project: You would need Pug to write those those templates and convert them to HTML. But say you want to test a few templates, then you could use Pug-cli for that, instead of building up your code and then looking in the HTML's.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install pug`: This is basically used in your current working project, it tells your node.js to render pug.

`npm install pug-cli -g`: using `pug-cli` gives you the power to be able to run your pug from the terminal, and including the `pug-cli -g` implies that your `pug-cli` will be installed globally which means you can run it from any `CWD` in your terminal.

Therefore all `-cli` (command line interface) modules have that ability of being ran directly from the terminal.